# google spreadsheet index match multiple column of same data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that has ChildName1, Childname2, parentemail

and am hoping to use index-match? or something at a separate sheet.

which has childname and parentemail

**sheet1** (survey that returns me those information):

```
CName1, CName2,   email1

danny,  andy,     hel@g.com

andrew, daniel,   asd@g.com
```

**sheet2** (have to create parentemail column)

```
time, childname parentemail

1,    danny,    hel@g.com

3,    andy,     hel@g.com

4,    andrew,   asd@g.com

9,    daniel,   asd@g.com
```

Any suggestions? I tried looking everywhere, and when I use

```
=index(Sheet1!C:C,match(B1,
Sheet1!A:A,0),match(B1,
Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

I get error

Comment: reason for not using query is because those two are seperate sets of data... sheet1 contains ALL students/parent info and sheet2 contains segment of student info...

Answer (score 0):

Paste this formula in Sheet2:

```
={{Sheet1!A2:A3;Sheet1!B2:B3},{Sheet1!C2:C3;Sheet1!C2:C3}}
```

test it in [this workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SopNJYVXIVa2bnpeZc-6UCGpwJDnsTg6EzOgm5sSqaM/edit?usp=sharing).

To add *Time* column you need to define it first in Sheet1.